# AWS s3 - Delete multiple objects in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete multiple objects in Amazon Cloud Service in Objective-C.

After searching the internet, all I could find is how to Delete only ONE object:

```
    AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
    AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest *deleteRequest = [AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest new];
    deleteRequest.bucket = yourBucket;
    deleteRequest.key = yourKey;
    [[s3 deleteObject:deleteRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        return task;
    }];
```

However, i want to be able to delete multiple objects from a bucket in one request. Please help!!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another call called AWSS3DeleteObjectsRequest (plural) that allows you to delete multiple objects if you know all of the keys. Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3DeleteObjectsRequest.html).

Comment: huh what documentation ?

Comment: The documentation linked in my answer... Here is the full URL if you would rather copy-paste than click the link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3DeleteObjectsRequest.html

Comment: @ChrisFranklin, could you please show an example to create `plural` which you passed to the method `AWSS3DeleteObjectsRequest (plural)`, trying to delete multiple objects in Swift. My SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47787676/2534233

Comment: @user44776 ```plural``` is not part of the request. It is simply pointing out that the correct method is a pluralized form of the original askers code ```AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest``` should be ```AWSS3DeleteObjectsRequest```.