# How to delete Multiple images from AWS S3 in objective c

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know how to delete single image from aws s3 but not idea about multiple images.

Comment: Are you using aws-sdk-ios ?

Comment: yes.. i am using aws sdk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS s3 - Delete multiple objects in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272862/aws-s3-delete-multiple-objects-in-ios)